# Plesk & postfix to send mail to a domain hosted on the server but mail managed externally

Tags: php, email, postfix-mta, plesk

I am running Plesk 11.5.30 on CentOS 6.4 with Postfix. I'm hosting two domains on this machine while the email of one of those domains is hosted externally.
 I'm using plain PHP sendmail to send email to a few recipients through a web form. Problem comes when I am trying to send an email to an email address that is on the domain with the mail service elsewhere. It mostly doesn't get delivered at all with some reports of significant delays sometimes (which I doubt, it should either work or not).

Here's my mail logs which I am quite new to and I don't understand: http://pastebin.com/U2YkpvUE

example2.co.uk is the domain with MX elsewhere.
 exampledomain.co.uk is the domain I'm sending from

Yes, I already tried turning off mail services like this: /usr/local/psa/bin/mail --off example2.co.uk - no luck, same reports.

Comment: Is you server correctly resolves MX record of you recipient domain: dig -tMX example2.co.uk ?

Comment: I've tried such config as yours on Plesk 12(postfix) and doesn't see any issue with sending to external mail service after switching off mail service on recipient domain.